# Regex : Replace All Uppercase in a Matched Group with a prefix

Tags: regex, perl

Assuming an SQL INSERT line for a database record:

```
.... ,'DateOfBirth' , N'DateOfBirth')
```

**How can I replace it to become the following, in a single Perl REGEX expression ?**

```
.... ,'DateOfBirth' , N'Date Of Birth')
```

The intention is to leave the first column untouched, while adding spaces to the second Description column.

The following are my findings:

```
Pattern: (, N'.+)([a-z])([A-Z])(.+)
Returns: ,'DateOfBirth' , N'DateOf Birth')  -- "DateOf" missed by the pattern.

Pattern: "[A-Z]" to replacement " \1" -- Gets the job done, but all Uppercase occurence impacted.
Returns: ,'Date Of Birth' , N'Date Of Birth')
```

Comment: How many different column names do you have to replace?

Comment: perl 5 or perl 6?

Comment: [You may use this regex: `(?:N'|(?!\A)\G)[A-Z][a-z]*`](https://regex101.com/r/svfUie/1)

Comment: Actually the regex pattern is being used in UltraEdit find/replace function (Perl syntax). Just this one column, but other records have other names like 'CountryOfDestination' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for searching:

```
/(?:N'|(?!\A)\G)[A-Z][a-z]*/g
```

and replace this with:

```
"$0 "
```

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. In this case we first find `N'` followed by an uppercase letter followed by 0 or more lowercase letters. Then insert a space at that place. Then using `\G` we find next match from end of previous match.

`(?!\A)` is negative lookahead to make sure we don't match start of line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/svfUie/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Perl's [join](/questions/tagged/join) way for better readability/maintainability :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

sub f {
    $_ = shift;
    return join " ", split /([A-Z]+[a-z]+)/;
}

while (<>) {
    s|(?<=N')([^']+)|f($1)|e;
    print;
}
```

Or in a shell :

```
$ echo ".... ,'DateOfBirth' , N'DateOfBirth')" | perl -pe '
    BEGIN{
        sub f {
            $_ = shift;
            return join " ", split /([A-Z]+[a-z]+)/;
        }
    }
    s|(?<=N\047)([^\047]+)|f($1)|e
'
```

### Output :

```
.... ,'DateOfBirth' ,  N'Date  Of  Birth')
```

### Note :

- `(?<=N')` is a [look around assertion](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)
- to do the trick, I run `f()` function in the substitution, permited by  the `e` modifier

Comment: Added perl version

Comment: Thanks, but since I was devising a 1-liner regex, this doesn't quite fit the bill. Will retain for future use.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:(?:\sN')?([A-Z][a-z]*)|(?:\1))(\1)*` matches `'Date'` `'Of'` and `'Birth'`

Comment: Thanks, but this pattern catches both 'DatOfBirth', so a no go for me.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution devised from answers provided, for UltraEdit Find/Replace (Boost C++ Perl 5.8 Regex Syntax):

```
Find Pattern:   
(N'[A-Z][a-z]+|\G)([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)

Replace Pattern:
\1\2 \3
\1 is (N'[A-Z][a-z]+|\G)
\2 is ([a-z]+)
\3 is ([A-Z]+)

Input:
.... ,'DateOfBirth' , N'DateOfBirth')

Output:
.... ,'DateOfBirth' , N'Date Of Birth')
```